# Conversion table for diacritics (e.g. "ü" → "ue")

Tags: umlaut, diacritic

I am looking for a table for converting German [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) into their non-diacritic character combination equivalent. For instance that table would indicate that the [umlaut *ü* may be converted to *ue*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9C#U-umlaut)).

Does such a table exist, and if so, could someone share a link to it?

Comment: Note: "it may be converted", but it's definitely wrong (and ugly) to do it in German.

Comment: @splattne: it's for use in URLs, see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33032/how-to-handle-urls-with-diacritic-characters#comment32233_33032. In that question I've given an example showing the Bundesliga using that approach, so I'm thinking it might not be that bad if such big companies are doing it.

Comment: you're right, in URLs and Internet domain name it's absolutely okay.

Comment: See also http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4994/is-the-eszett-ss-used-in-last-names German ID-cards use converted names in the machine readable zone.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- ä → ae
- ö → oe
- ü → ue
- Ä → Ae
- Ö → Oe
- Ü → Ue
- ß → ss (or SZ)

The SZ is only for words in capitals (and I think for old spelling).

Für [LaTeX-Nutzer](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umlaut#TeX_und_LaTeX) gibt es auch die Umschreibung "a, "o, "u, bzw. "A, "O, "U (bzw. \"a, \"o, \"u, bzw. \"A, \"O, \"U)

---

You are also asking for a kind of official link.

Maybe [Din 5007](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetische_Sortierung) helps a bit. That's a norm for sorting. An "ä" is either treated like an "a" (variant 1 of DIN 5007) or like an "ae" (variant 2).

Comment: We should add that if the whole word is in capitals we may  convert like AE, UE, ...

Comment: "SZ" for "ß" is old and obsolte. Always replace "ß" by "SS" if the word must be written in capitals. In swizzerland you don't use "ß". The swizz name for the letter "ß" is "Doppel s". In Germany "ß" is called "esszet" and in Austria "scharfes s".

Comment: There is in meantime also a [capital-ß](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_ẞ). It's unicode U+1E9E

Comment: The only occurrence of SZ for ß I ever heard of was on teletypes for military communications.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: In *Northern* Germany it is called "eszett". In Southern Germany, as in Austria, it's "scharfes s".

Comment: @starblue: AFAIK before the spelling reform, you were supposed to use SZ in cases where there's another word which is written with ss. For example, you'd capitalize "in Maßen" as "IN MASZEN" because there's also "in Massen" which gets capitalized as "IN MASSEN".

Comment: As an aside the conversion from ß -> ss is (unfortunately) lossy. My understanding is that ß will make a preceding a long, but ss will not.

Comment: @celtschk   In parts of Southern Germany we also use to call it *Buckel-s*.

Answer (score 3):

For another official link I recommend the [ICU project](http://site.icu-project.org/) (International Components for Unicode). It basically is a database for all(?) languages/scripts and how to convert, sort and compare words to be used by computer programs.

They have a [ICU Transform Demonstration](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/translit) which demonstrates the transform rules. For German, you can start with "Latin" as "Source 1" and "ASCII" as "Target 1". The example "Names (Variant)" is very impressive as well as it can transliterate Korean(?), Cyrillic, Greek to Latin.

Comment: I think the Latin->ASCII transform you describe with convert "ä", "ö", and "ü" to "a", "o", and "u", respectively, not "ae", "oe", and "ue".

Comment: This was fixed in the latest release of ICU 60, you can now use the `de-ASCII` transform to convert german text into ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for replace the German Umlaute with cleverly **respecting the case**, use this (opensource, happy to share, all by me) in **JavaScript**:

```
let umlautMap = {
  '\u00dc': 'UE',
  '\u00c4': 'AE',
  '\u00d6': 'OE',
  '\u00fc': 'ue',
  '\u00e4': 'ae',
  '\u00f6': 'oe',
  '\u00df': 'ss',
}

function replaceUmlaute(str) {
  return str
    .replace(/[\u00dc|\u00c4|\u00d6][a-z]/g, (a) => {
      var big = umlautMap[a.slice(0, 1)];
      return big.charAt(0) + big.charAt(1).toLowerCase() + a.slice(1);
    })
    .replace(new RegExp('['+Object.keys(umlautMap).join('|')+']',"g"),
      (a) => umlautMap[a]
    );
}
```

It will:

- Übung -> Uebung
- ÜBUNG -> UEBUNG
- üben -> ueben
- einüben -> einueben
- EINÜBEN -> EINUEBEN
- and the same for Ä, Ö
- and simple ß -> ss

Comment: It would help if you added which language that's in

Comment: Thank you for a nice code! Couple adjustments I did - the pipe (`|`) inside `[]` character group is unnecessary, and it would match `|u` in `Üb|ung` erroneously. And also, there's now a [capital ẞ](https://unicode-table.com/en/1E9E/).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Knuts answer:

In July 2017 the "Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung" [declared](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_PM_2017-06-29_Aktualisierung_Regelwerk.pdf), that it is allowed to use the [Capital ẞ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E) as well as SS when capitalizing ß.

Therefore a capitalized ß results in **SS** or **ẞ**.

Please pay attention, that a lot of fonts do not contain this letter.